# Discord Java Bot does not respond

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

So my discord Bot does not respond to my messages :/
Here is my code. Maybe you can help me.

```
    public static JDA jda;
    public static String prefix = "+";
    
    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws LoginException{
        
        jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(REDACTED).build();
        jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.DO_NOT_DISTURB);
        jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.watching("Im watching you"));
        
        jda.addEventListener(new Commands());
        
    }
}
```

Command Listener:

```
    public void onGuildMessageRecived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        
        
        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "info")) {
            
            event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Started on 09.01.2021").queue();
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to register the EventListener first and then build the Bot.

Answer (score 0):

Do have the ListenerAdapter extended?

```
public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {
```